# Mixed-effect coefficients at nonexistent levels

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, linear-model, multilevel-analysis

Suppose I recorded successes and failures for two different conditions organized into two different blocks. However, one of the conditions (`Trt`) was just in first of the blocks. I repeated the exercise twice. So we have:

```
dat = data.frame(
  Cond    = c(rep('Neg', 4), 'Trt', 'Trt'),
  Block   = c(rep(1:2, 2), 1, 1),
  Rep     = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2),
  Success = c(146, 143, 174, 136, 72, 136),
  Failure = c(500, 445, 570, 685, 299, 211)
)

#   Cond Block Rep Success Failure
# 1  Neg     1   1     146     500
# 2  Neg     2   1     143     445
# 3  Neg     1   2     174     570
# 4  Neg     2   2     136     685
# 5  Trt     1   1      72     299
# 6  Trt     1   2     136     211
```

Now, if I try to model this:

```
library(nlme4)
m1 = glmer(cbind(Success, Failure) ~ Cond + (Cond|Block), 
  binomial, data = dat)
coef(m1)[1]
# $Block
#   (Intercept)   CondTrt
# 1   -1.250252 0.3533767
# 2   -1.353067 0.4562030
```

Why do I get `Trt` coefficient also for second block? What does the coefficient mean?

Comment: Can you also post `summary(m1)`?

Comment: I could, but why? I would assume it is better to keep it short but reproducible.

Comment: Do you only have two blocks in your larger dataset? If not, how many do you have? With only two blocks, a random intercept is not appropriate. Treat it as a "fixed" intercept in an GLM.

Comment: Indeed, the larger dataset has five blocks and thousands of conditions. I am aware that even five is not much and I should treat block as a "fixed" intercept. I was just confused/curious as to what do such coefficients mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that, as Erik mentioned in a comment, this model does not make a lot of sense, because you have specified `Block` as a grouping factor for random intercepts when it only has two levels. So, you are asking the software to estimate the variance for a normally distributed variable from only 2 observations. A better model would be:

```
glm(cbind(Success, Failure) ~ Cond + Block, binomial, data = dat)
```

Second, regarding the output of `coef()`, I agree that this seems somewhat confusing. However, we have to bear in mind that in `lme4` the random effects follow a multivariate normal distribution, so it would be impossible to have a different number of random effects for the intercept and the slopes. Regarding the interpretation of this, I think you could interpret it as a prediction.